# Avast antivirus virus alarm while programming

Tags: antivirus, compiler

I was programming a function pointer in C on CodeBlocks. When I compiled and ran it, Avast showed an alert message and quarantined the .exe.

Is there a solution? Or do I need to disable Avast while programming?

Comment: I like Avast, but as a programmer, it annoys me. Even just running my application requires a full "scan" of the app, which starts the application, scans it in a sandbox, terminates it, then starts it again, which the debugger doesn't always catch. Eventually I ditched it for MS tools built-in to W10.

Comment: so, know another better antivirus to programmers? thats the correct question, then

Answer (score 1):

Do not turn off your protection. In Avast, just like in most antivirus software, it's possible to add [exceptions](https://www.getavast.net/support/managing-exceptions) on a whitelist.

> Quick Summary
>
> 1. Make sure the blocked file or webpage is not malicious by testing it at www.virustotal.com
> 2. Add it as an exception by going to Settings » General » Exclusions
> 3. Confirm by clicking OK

It should be safe to add the folder where you keep (just) your own software to the whitelist. However, it might be a good idea to manually test the final version before publishing to avoid false positives that may harm your reputation. You could also use the name and description of the dedection to investigate whether your software actually has malware like characteristics.